# Como enviar un array a mi controlador SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Tengo un script en el cual guardo algunos datos en un array, el cual necesito de alguna manera que llegue a mi controlador para trabajar con el, este es mi script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
                var table = $('#tableImport').DataTable({
            } );
            $("#validateCustomers").click(function() {
            const array2 = new Array();
            table.$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                        $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
                          array2.push($(this).text());
                        });
                        });
            console.log(array2);
                        })
            } );
```

Este es el metodo en mi controlador a donde necesito que llegue el array:

```
@GetMapping("/addSelected")
    public String saveSelected(@RequestParam(value = "customersSelecteds") String[] customersSelecteds){
        
        return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
    }
```

Comment: Hola. Puedes enviar el arreglo por ajax, enviando los datos como `data: JSON.stringify(array2)`

Comment: Podrias mostrarme un ejemplo, de como lo recibo en el controller?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar los datos por Ajax de la siguiente forma

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#tableImport').DataTable({

  });

  $("#validateCustomers").click(function() {
    const array2 = new Array();
    table.$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
      $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
        array2.push($(this).text());
      });
    });
    console.log(array2);

    $.ajax({
      url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addSelected',
      method: 'GET',
      traditional: true,
      data: JSON.stringify(array2),
      success: function(data) {
        //action after success
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        alert("The request failed: " + request.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Para recibir dichos parámetros tienes que modificar tu metodo en el controlador de la siguiente forma:

```
@GetMapping("/addSelected")
public String saveSelected(@RequestBody String[] customersSelecteds){
  return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
}
```

De esta forma recibirás lo que envíes desde el ajax a tu controlador